# How come the range includes the last number in generating a random number while it doesn't get included in for loops and indexing?

Tags: python

I always thought that the last number of range was the "cutoff" so it was not really included when I state it. Now I am kind of confused why it got selected in printing random numbers from (0, 5) with `random.randint`.

```
import random
number1 = random.randint(0,5)
print(number1)
number2 = range(0, 5)
for i in number2:
    print(i)
```

Output:

5
0
1
2
3
4

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `range`, both the arguments to [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) are inclusive, so `random.randint(a, b)` will generate a random number N satisfying a <= N <= b. For a more direct analog to `range`, you can use [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) which is end-disclusive.